# Qlikview - sum in expressions

Tags: qlikview

When I press buton I activate sheet where I have the trigger
                                                                           onActivate sheet  -> Select In Field -> Posting Month -> (JAN|FEB|MAR)

and I need expression to show bar chart with price for month jan,feb,mar
I create this expression

```
if(PostingMonth = 'JAN' ,Sum(Price))
+ if(PostingMonth = 'FEB' ,Sum(Price)) 
+ if(PostingMonth = 'MAR' ,Sum(Price))
```

but I got No data to displey.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sum({<PostingMonth = {'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR'}>} Price)`